# converting json date regardless timezone

Tags: javascript, json

I'm looking to get a date when literally no time zone is applied in any case. In the example code I get totally different results in IE and Chrome. I need to get "7" in any case. What is the correct way?

```
$('#result')[0].innerText = "JSon: 2015-03-13T07:30:00 \n" + "As Date: " + new Date("2015-03-13T07:30:00") + "\n" + "Hours Part:" + new Date("2015-03-13T07:30:00").getHours();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xtjbvcpw/2/

Thanks.

Comment: might be better off just treating that date as a string and doing a substring operation, e.g. `str.substr(str.indexOf('T')+1, 2)`

Comment: A date/time cannot exist independent of a time zone. A date/time is always defined as being at a particular offset from GMT.

Comment: You could use UTC. So in order to get hours for the date in UTC format you will do something like this new Date('%datestring%').getUTCHours(), for minutes there is getUTCMinutes(). Here is a reference for all the Date objects methods http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: getUTCHours also returns different values depending on the browser. I need the same result in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't exactly answer your question, one option would be to use a javascript module to handle the timezone issue (including operating in a fixed and/or arbitrary timezone).  I have use [`moment-timezone`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) in the past to great success.